# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote

Tags: linux, ssh

after a few hours of asking google ( and a lot of serverfault pages ) i didnt found a answer.

After arround 100 ssh login's the server answers : "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote".

The ssh -vvv log:

```
ssh -vvv root@192.168.3.18
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7.1, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.3.18 [192.168.3.18] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/bla/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bla/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bla/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

if one terminal is already opend, the status is:

```
root@snr2:~ systemctl status sshd.socket
sshd.socket
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sshd.socket; disabled)
      Active: failed since Fri, 06 Mar 2015 07:40:16 +0000; 3s ago
    Accepted: 2092; Connected: 2
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/sshd.socket
```

after restarting

```
root@snr2:~ systemctl restart sshd.socket
root@snr2:~ systemctl status sshd.socket
sshd.socket
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sshd.socket; disabled)
      Active: active (listening) since Fri, 06 Mar 2015 07:42:04 +0000; 1s ago
    Accepted: 2092; Connected: 2
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/sshd.socket
```

and now its not possible to login again, i need to restart the complete machine, not only the sshd service.

what i have tried:

```
 echo "sshd:ALL" >> /etc/hosts.allow
```

the /etc/ssh directory looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           480 Jan  8  1970 backup
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        125811 Jan  1  1970 moduli
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1355 Feb 26 05:52 ssh_config
-rw-------    1 root     root           668 Jan  8  1970 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           608 Jan  8  1970 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------    1 root     root          1679 Jan  8  1970 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           400 Jan  8  1970 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2870 Mar  5 12:46 sshd_config
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2870 Mar  5 12:46 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

ive tried to delete the ssh_host_{rsa,dsa}_* files but then its not possible to login again.

```
#      $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.73 2005/12/06 22:38:28 reyk Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

Port 22
Protocol 2
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication mechanism.
# Depending on your PAM configuration, this may bypass the setting of
# PasswordAuthentication, PermitEmptyPasswords, and
# "PermitRootLogin without-password". If you just want the PAM account and
# session checks to run without PAM authentication, then enable this but set
# ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no
#UsePAM no

#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid

MaxStartups 100
#PermitTunnel no

# no default banner path
#Banner /some/path

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem      sftp    /usr/sbin/sftp-server
```

hopefully someone could help me :)

greetings

Comment: Any chance you're getting low on memory?  One cause of this is the userspace daemon not being able to start, so the kernel closes the connection down.  What's in your system logs about this time?

Comment: The most important logs here are the ones on the server side. The user side cannot give you all the information.

Comment: @MadHatter, i dont think so, i have the feeling that only my ip is bloacked.... please tell me in which logs i should look

Comment: My initial thought was fail2ban or similar on the server but that wouldn't cause the service to be disabled. It feels more like resource exhaustion - hopefully something in /var/log/messages.

Comment: look if there are some firewall rules that think the "flod" of connections are too many, consider to whitelist your ip.

Comment: @JennyD makes a strong point that I'd taken for granted - it is the server logs that will tell you what's going on, and to which I was referring.  You do have admin access to the server, don't you?  And I think you're wrong about the IP blocking, because the initial handshake is going through fine.  As Paul says (and I'd already said), resource exhaustion on the server is likely to be the culprit.

Comment: @user274797 What logs to look in will depend on how syslog is configured on the server. Probably one or more of `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure` will have the answers. Grep for `sshd` and/or for your own IP address.

Comment: thanks for the fast replay. on this installation there are only btmp        daemon.log  kern.log    lighttpd/   user.log    wtmp
files. Administration istn a part of my work :-/ could you tell me where i should have a look on ? In the /var/log/daemon.log there are many lines like: /var/log/daemon.log:2015-03-06T07:50:07+00:00 snr2 systemd[1]: sshd@192.168.3.18:22-192.168.2.18:49444.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255
/var/log/daemon.log:2015-03-06T07:50:07+00:00 snr2 systemd[1]: Unit sshd@192.168.3.18:22-192.168.2.18:49444.service entered failed state

Comment: @Roby sorry, are you the person who asked the original question?  That said, `sshd...service: main process exited` and `Unit sshd...service entered failed state` are fairly damning.  This isn't IP blocking.  Something's killing the daemon on the server, and my bet's still on memory exhaustion.

Comment: @MadHatter, oh yes im the poster :). If i reboot the complete system and then doing many logins, i get this fault, no "unnormal" process is running , top showes memory free % of ~80

Comment: @Roby firstly, you should ask for the two accounts to be merged, see instructions in http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6282/merge-unregistered-user-account-with-registered-account ; otherwise you won't be able to do the housekeeping that the community expects of you.  Secondly, *something* is killing `sshd`; it's not the sort of daemon that falls over without a push.  You need to find out what it is, and the vital clue is likely in those server logs, probably shortly before `sshd...service: main process exited`.